A Social Welfare Function that violates Non Dictatorship
The question is to give an example of a Social Welfare Function that violates the Non Dictatorship criteria. Now the existence of such a SWF is guaranteed by the Arrow's Impossibility theorem, but I am having a really hard time to actually come up with an example.
Let
$$\mathbb{X} = \text{The set of alternatives} \\
\mathbb{N} = \text{The set of individuals} = \{1, 2, \dots, n\} \\
R_i = \text{ Weak preference relation of individual $i$}\\
P_i = \text{ Strict preference relation of individual $i$} \\
\mathcal{R} = \text{Weak Social prefernce} \\
\mathcal{P} = \text{Strict Social prefernce} $$
Now,if I define a SCR as follows where
$$(\forall x,y \in \mathbb{X})[xP_jy \rightarrow x\mathcal{P}y, xR_jy \rightarrow x\mathcal{R}y,]$$
where I am claiming j to be the dictator. Is this a valid example? I also need to ensure that this is indeed a SWF, that is, it must be an Ordering too.The idea that I am trying to implement is that the Social rankings mimic exactly the individual rankings of individual $j$ (not only when j strictly prefers x over y, as is required by the existence of a Dictator), disregarding the prefernces of all other individuals.
On a slightly unrelated note $\dots$ two Social Choice Rules defined as follows:
$$
(\forall x,y \in \mathbb{X})[x\mathcal{R}y \iff xR_jy] \dots(1) \\
(\forall x,y \in \mathbb{X})[x\mathcal{P}y \iff xP_jy] \dots(2) 
$$
Are they equivalent? I dont think so because although $x\mathcal{P}y \Rightarrow x\mathcal{R}y \text{ but } \neg (x\mathcal{R}y \Rightarrow x\mathcal{P}y)$ ( I am thinking when the individual j is indifferent between x and y, aRy holds but not xPy.)
Moreover, are both of them oderings? Again, I think (1) is but not (2).
Thanks in advance!
